# Newton-Raphson Division For Floating Point Divide?

Tags: matlab, binary, floating-point, division, newtons-method

I am trying to implement the Newton-Raphson Division Algorithm [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) to implement a IEEE-754 32-bit floating point divide on a processor which has no hardware divide unit.

My memory locations are 32-bit two's complement word and I have already implemented floating point addition, subtraction, and multiplication, so I can reuse the code to implement the Newton-Raphson algorithm. I am trying to first implement this all in Matlab.

At this step:
    X_0 = 48/17 - 32/17 * D
How do I bitshift D properly to between 0.5 and 1 as described in the algorithm details?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the compiler-rt runtime library (part of LLVM), which has a liberal license and implements floating-point operations for processors that lack hardware support.

You could also look at libgcc, though I believe that's GPL, which may or may not be an issue for you.

In fact, don't just look at them.  Use one of them (or another soft-float library).  There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Sometimes an existing implementation may not be suitable. In any case, compiler-rt version does not return a correctly-rounded result when the result is subnormal.